# On setting doesRelativeDateFormatting = YES, stringFromDate returns nil

Tags: ios, iphone, nsdateformatter

In the NSDateFormatter documentation,

> If a date formatter uses relative date formatting, where possible it replaces the date component of its output with a phrase—such as “today” or “tomorrow”—that indicates a relative date.

I am using the following code:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.dateFormat = [NSDateFormatter dateFormatFromTemplate:@"EEEE dMMMM',' hma"
                                                       options:0
                                                        locale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
formatter.doesRelativeDateFormatting = YES;
NSLog(@"Date: %@", [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]);
```

It logs `Date:`.

But on commenting out `formatter.doesRelativeDateFormatting = YES;` the output comes out correct.

`Date: Tuesday, 19 August 1:18 pm`

Am I understanding `doesRelativeDateFormatting` wrong?

Answer (score 6):

Hi when i modified code like this. it works..

```
 NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 formatter.dateFormat = [NSDateFormatter dateFormatFromTemplate:@"EEEE dMMMM',' hma"
                                                       options:0
                                                        locale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
 [formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterFullStyle];
 [formatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
 formatter.doesRelativeDateFormatting = YES;
  NSLog(@"Date: %@", [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]);
```

Comment: Resetting the `dateStyle` breaks the added `dateFormat`. This logs `Date: Today` instead of `Date: Today, current_time`.

Comment: Hi @AyushGoel I have updated the code. please check now..default time style is `NSDateFormatterNoStyle` that is why you are not getting time.But i have updated time style to `NSDateFormatterShortStyle`.Now its working. There are other formats too. i.e NSDateFormatterNoStyle, NSDateFormatterShortStyle, NSDateFormatterMediumStyle, NSDateFormatterLongStyle, NSDateFormatterFullStyle.

Comment: Hey, resetting the date and time style also updates the `dateFormat` of the `NSDateFormatter`. 

`NSLog(@"%@ Date: %@", formatter.dateFormat, [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:-10000000]]);` gives `EEEE, d MMMM y h:mm a Date: Thursday, 1 May 2014 4:58 am`. 

Do notice that the new `dateFormat` contains `y` which was not supposed to be there.

Answer (score 5):

It seems like `doesRelativeDateFormatting` doesn't work with a custom `dateFormat`.

I had the same challenge as you to display `Today, 11:44 pm` or `19 Aug, 1:23 am`. The hard part being that the year was to be always excluded.

I solved it like this:

**Get a formatted date any style you like, with `doesRelativeDateFormatting` enabled**

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.MediumStyle
dateFormatter.doesRelativeDateFormatting = true
var dateString = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(dateToFormat)
```

**Get the formatted year from the same date** (make sure the `dateFormat` has the correct number of y's to represent the year. I use 4 y's because the Medium date style uses the full year format.

```
let yearFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
yearFormatter.dateFormat = NSDateFormatter.dateFormatFromTemplate("yyyy", options: 0, locale: NSLocale.currentLocale())
let yearString = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(dateToFormat)
```

**Finally compose the final string by removing the year from the generated `dateString` and trimming some excess white space.**

```
var finalString = dateString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(yearString, withString: "")
finalString = finalString.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())
```

It's not an ideal solution because I'm sure there will be some locale where the year is formatted right between the day and month or something, which would create a funky looking string. But it works in all my tested cases.

Comment: Also some date formats include comma before or after date, be aware when just stripping a year!

Comment: @rshev Exactly, that's why I said it's not an ideal solution.